# Run command dotnet --list-sdks did not return result

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I run `dotnet --list-sdks`, but it shows no installed SDKs:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1320]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhuvy>dotnet --list-sdks

C:\Users\donhuvy>
```

And:

```
C:\Users\donhuvy>where dotnet
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

[image]

Comment: It is `--list-sdks`, with an `s` at the end...

Comment: Yes. `dotnet --list-sdks` (has `s` ). It did not work.

Comment: So why do you show all that error output? What is the relevance of the latest screenshot? Your issue is with `--list-sdks` showing zero SDKs, are those SDKs actually installed?

Comment: I download it likes this https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.403-windows-x64-installer , then install. It's SDK, not runtime. It does not show any error, just return nothing.

Comment: It is just a guess but try to run dotnet --list-sdks in administrator mode.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide all relavant details and show what you have tried, don't have users fishing for details. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3242 - what is your PATH environment variable order, does the x86 version get listed first? Have you uninstalled and reinstalled the SDKs? Do you run the 64-bit cmd?

Comment: @dotnetstep https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/141114893-74c81d20-e733-40de-ada3-c67f53107395.png

Comment: Check output of `dotnet --info`. My guess would be that x86 version is used and it does not find x64 SDKs

Comment: According to your `where` output, the x86 path to the SDKs is indeed listed first. Move those around in your system settings (or remove the 32-bit version) and restart your console.

Comment: @CodeCaster It seems to be solution.